# Error: Installed PyTorch but getting 'No module named torch' on Windows

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I am trying to run a GitHub repository and have followed all the provided steps. I created a Conda environment with the required Python version(python=3.8.5) and installed all the necessary packages, ensuring that I used the suggested versions specified by the repository. However, when I attempt to run their train script, I encounter a 'No module named torch' error related to PyTorch.

Here are the details of what I have tried so far:

I can successfully import PyTorch in the Python terminal, indicating that it is installed correctly.

I verified that I installed the correct version of PyTorch. My system has a GPU, and I have the following information:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.91
```

The installation command I used was:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

I attempted to check the cuDNN version, but I couldn't find the cudnn.h file at the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Comment: Just checking; are you sure the conda env is activated? Also, please include the Github repo.